# Match backslash followed by escape character

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match a backslash followed by an escape character like `t`, `n`, `r`, or `\`.. like in a JSON string. To simplify, only consider `\t` and `\\`.. For example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my @data = (
    [q{\t},    qr/\\t/],            #ok
    ["\\",     qr/\\/],             #ok
    ["\\",     qr/[\\]/],           #ok
    ["\t",     qr/\t/],             #ok
    ["\t",     qr/[\t]/],           #ok
    [q{\\\t},  qr/(\\[\\\t])*/],    #not ok
    [q{\\\t},  qr/(\\\\[\\\\t])*/ ],#ok
);

for my $i (0..$#data) {
    my ($str, $regex) = @{$data[$i]};
    my $match_result = ($str =~ /^$regex$/) ? "ok" : "not ok";
    say(
        "$i : "
         . dump( $str )
         . ' =~ '
         . dump( $regex )
         . ' : '
         . $match_result
     );
}
```

Output:

```
0 : "\\t" =~ qr/\\t/ : ok
1 : "\\" =~ qr/\\/ : ok
2 : "\\" =~ qr/[\\]/ : ok
3 : "\t" =~ qr/\t/ : ok
4 : "\t" =~ qr/[\t]/ : ok
5 : "\\\\t" =~ qr/(\\[\\\t])*/ : not ok
6 : "\\\\t" =~ qr/(\\\\[\\\\t])*/ : ok
```

The question is, why does test #5 fail. I would think that it would be the correct regex to use..What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Item 5 is

```
q{\\\t} =~ qr/(\\[\\\t])*/
```

`q{\\\t}`, which is equivalent to `'\\\t'`. Within a single-quoted string there is no need to escape anything except

- the delimiter character
- a backslash immediately before the closing delimiter or another backslash

also, any occurrence of two backslashes together is taken as an escaped backslash.

So `'\\\t'` is a three-character string containing `\` `\` `t`.

The contents of `qr//` behaves as double-quote context, so *all* backslashes need to be escaped, and may modify the following character.

`"(\\[\\\t])*"` is the eight-character string consisting of `(` `\` `[` `\` `\t` `]` `)` `*` where `\t` is `"\x09"` - the tab character. So your pattern will match a string that consists of a backslash followed by a tab or a backslash, all repeated zero or more times. There are only backslashes and a `t` in the string so it cannot match.

I hope that helps. The bottom line is that there are no escape sequences inside single quotes except to protect the backslash and the delimiter, and `'\t'` means exactly *backslash, small letter t*

Comment: Thanks for the nice clarification! There are at least two things that I missed. First, a double backslash within `q` counts as a single backslash. So the the seven chraracter argument to `q{\\\\\\t}`, becomes a 4 character length string. The second thing was that, as you pointed out, `\t` becomes `\x09` inside `qr`. So what I meant to do for test #5 was probably `[q{\\\\\\t},  qr/(\\[t\\])*/]`

Comment: @HåkonHægland: It sounds like you've grasped it. Many don't realise that, within single quotes, *single* backslashes are retained and don't need doubling up. That means Windows paths like `'C:\Windows\System32\drivers'` is fine. The only problem comes when you need a trailing backslash which *does* have to be escaped, or a UNC path like `\\SERVER\backup\20150415` has to be expressed as `'\\\\SERVER\backup\20150415'`. (Actually only three backslashes at the start are necessary there, but four seems better.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the following:

```
q{\\\t}
```

is

```
"\\\\t"
```

which is 3 characters, 2 backslashes followed by a 't'

Your regular expression #5 matches an arbritray number of pairs of characters (a \ followed by another \ or a < tabulator >)

changing this to

```
[q{\\\t},  qr/(\\[\\\t]*)*/],    #not ok
```

would still be not ok,

but

```
[q{\\\t},  qr/(\\[\\t]*)*/],    #ok
```

would work.

HTH
Georg